# Setting values in AndroidManifes.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest

Is it possible to set values in AndroidManifest.xml by code?

For example I want to set android:largeHeap="true", but it is possible only in 3.x platforms; but my application must run on 2.2 and above. 
Then I want to set android:largeHeap="true" on 3.x platforms and do nothing on 2.x platforms by code.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is NOT possible to change Manifest at runtime..

from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) :

> The manifest presents essential information about the application to
>   the Android system, information the system must have **before it can run**
>   any of the application's code.

plus:

> These declarations let the Android system know what the components are
>   and under what conditions they can be launched.

so everything is specified before running and then your App runs, under permissions and conditions Android system gave to it.

cheers